# Is there an environment in ConTeXt to center a poem?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context, verse

I want to center the poem written by William Blake. Is there an environment in ConTeXt to achieve this?

My only method is the `midaligned`

```
\midaligned{To see a world in a grain of sand}
\midaligned{And a heaven in a wild fllower}
\midaligned{Hold infinity in the palm of your hand}
\midaligned{And eternity in an hour}
```

but it's not elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`lines`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verse).

```
\starttext
\setuplines[align=middle]
\startlines
To see a world in a grain of sand
And a heaven in a wild flower
Hold infinity in the palm of your hand
And eternity in an hour
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

Comment: Normally, one uses `align=middle` rather than `align=center`. (I am actually surprised that `align=center` works!)

Comment: @Aditya Oh, I'll fix that. I don't really use ConTeXt, so I just tried it, and it worked.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the features of ConTeXt. You try the logical thing and it works :)

Comment: @Aditya `"You try the logical thing and it works"` exactly